# How can I get the count of downloads in google play programatically

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery

I have uploaded my Android app in Google Play... The downloads whatever is displaying in Google Play of my app... I need that count in my website. So, please help me out with this.

Comment: 7 questions , 0 accepted?  accept some answers so others will be motivated to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is not possible. The only indication you can get is a range between it's been downloaded. For example between 50 - 100.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Can you tell me how to get the range between it's downloaded.